# maximize combination(n, x) * combination(n, y)

Tags: optimization, combinations

I have `3x + y = 1100`, the combination x samples out of 500 `C(500, x)` and the combination y samples out of 500 `C(500, y)`.
I want to maximize `C(500, x) * C(500, y)`.

Any one could you solve `x`, `y` using high school math? Thanks a lot!

A intuition would be letting x and y be as close as possible to 250 to max the combination. I got the formula to minimize `(250 - x)^2 + (250 - y)^2` but I don't know if there is any theory supporting this.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I do not know of any good way to do this with pen-and-paper or with tools learned in high school.  It is false that the product is maximized when $x$ and $y$ are equal.  From trial and error / brute force... one can find that it is maximized with $x=280,~y=260$ with $\binom{500}{x}\binom{500}{y}$ being $\approx 2.494\times 10^{296}$.  Moving $x$ in either direction takes it to $2.39\times 10^{296}$